# Display items of JSON using id identifier

Tags: php, json

I have a blog API in JSON that i'm trying to use with PHP. I have a page called 'index.php' that lists all the posts in the blog pulled from the JSON file,  and passes an id to another page 'post.php' from a href link to that page.

I need The 'post.php' page to hold a single post identified by the id sent from 'index.php' when the user clicks on the chosen post

I am displaying title and other property as below:

```
<h2><?php echo $post->title ?></h2>
```

but I need to do something like

```
<h2><?php echo $post->id->$post->title ?></h2>
```

to ensure that only the post with the given id is displayed
Below is an excerpt of the JSON

```
{


"posts": [
    {
      "type": "post",
      "date": "2017-04-11T13:36:46+00:00",
      "title": "Title here",

      "content": "my content"    
      "author": {
        "id": 878,
        "nicename": "tretr",
        "display_name": "name here",
        "user_url": "",
        "posts_url": "https:\\/\\/blogs.kent.ac.uk\\/kbs-news-events\\/author\\/cmb58\\/",
        "meta": {
          "description": "",
          "first_name": "first name",
          "last_name": "last name",

        }
      },

      "id": 1234,
      "permalink": "https:\/\/ link.....",
      "modified": "2017-04-11T13:39:36+00:00",
      "excerpt": "more here",
      "meta": [],

      etc.......
    }
  ],
  "http_status": 200
}
```

Comment: What you want to extract from this json ?

Comment: hi sorry not sure what you mean

Comment: I need Title, date,  and content

Comment: updated my post You can check.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally the blog API you use should return id based records, so that you have a list API and a view API that returns a single post.
If not, I'll advise you to loop through and change the format of the current JSON structure to something like this:

```
{
    "posts": {
        "1234": {
            "type": "post",
            "date": "2017-04-11T13:36:46+00:00",
            "title": "Title here",
            "content": "my content",
            "author": {
                "id": 878,
                "nicename": "tretr",
                "display_name": "name here",
                "user_url": "",
                "posts_url": "https:\\/\\/blogs.kent.ac.uk\\/kbs-news-events\\/author\\/cmb58\\/",
                "meta": {
                    "description": "",
                    "first_name": "first name",
                    "last_name": "last name"
                }
            },
            "id": 1234,
            "permalink": "https:// link.....",
            "modified": "2017-04-11T13:39:36+00:00",
            "excerpt": "more here",
            "meta": []
        }
    },
    "http_status": 200
}
```

Notice the `"1234" : {}` key added, changing each post array into a JavaScript object. Using this, you can now access each post by `$post->id->title`

---

Edit
As per your comment, you can use the api as follows:
    $data = json_decode(file_get_contents('http://api.kent.ac.uk/api/v1/blogs/music-matters/8192'));
    echo $data->title;

Comment: hi and thanks. I can return an individual post with: https://api.kent.ac.uk/api/v1/blogs/music-matters/8192 would i be able to use this?